# Move files from amazon glacier vault to azure storage account

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, amazon-s3, amazon-glacier, azcopy

I have data which is directly moved to amazon glacier vault. I had found that azcopy v10 is supporting copying data from s3 buckets to azure storage account. Still my data is present on glacier vault.

Can anyone suggest a way to copy the data from amazon glacier vault data (which doesn't have any S3 bucket for it) to azure storage account.

Comment: You would need to submit a job to retrieve the data from Glacier. Once the data is available, you would download the data. Then, you could upload it to the other storage destination.

Comment: I'm checking for an option to transfer the vault data to either s3 bucket or azure storage account. Because I dont have space in local to download all the files.

Comment: It is not possible to send directly from a Glacier Vault to Amazon S3. You would need to go via a computer that is calling the Glacier API. You could use a temporary Amazon EC2 instance as the intermediary. For ease of management, I'd recommend a Windows instance running some utility that knows how to communicate with Glacier, such as [Amazon Glacier Client for Windows | CloudBerry Lab](https://www.cloudberrylab.com/explorer/amazon-glacier.aspx) or [CloudBerry S3 Explorer](https://www.cloudberrylab.com/resources/blog/introducing-glacier-support-for-explorer/).